# Different rewrite rule redirect same url

Tags: nginx

`rewrite ^/old-url /new-url permanent;
 rewrite ^/old-url/old-url-sub /new-url/new-url-sub permanent;`

2 urls are (/old-url and old-url/old-url-sub) redirected to same url (**/new-url**)

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the regular expression `^/old-url` matches `/old-url` and `/old-url/old-url-sub` and `/old-url/anything-else`.

So the first `rewrite` statement is invoked for both URIs.

If you want a regular expression to match the entire string only, you need to use an anchor at the front and the back of the pattern. As you know, the `^` anchors the front of the pattern, whereas `$` anchors the back of the pattern.

Try:

```
rewrite ^/old-url$ /new-url permanent;
```

---

If you were trying to redirect `/old-url/xxx` to `/new-url/xxx` where `xxx` is anything, you would use a single `rewrite` statement with a capture:

```
rewrite ^/old-url(/.*)?$ /new-url$1 permanent;
```

See [this useful resource on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).

Comment: rewrite ^/old-url$ /new-url permanent; this line solved the problem. thanks